# Jquery.Cycle and IE7 including next Div

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

I'd really appreciate if someone could help me with a strange problem with Jquery.cycle.

I've added jQuery.cycle (version 2.72) into a existing application (Prestashop) to slideshow a number of images.  On Firefox, Mozilla etc it works brilliantly - on IE7 a bizarre problem occurs.

The problem is where I have a `<div class="pics" id="pics">` and say 6 pictures `</div>` a couple of `<div><br></div>` to break things up then another `<div id="editorial> content </div>` and IE includes the `"editorial"` into the slideshow.  The `"editorial"` block is removed from the page, and appears as the last slide in the slideshow, located in the top left corner.

Additional facts: jquery-1.2.6 is in use for the rest of the application (I've tried to upgrade it and all I get is the same behaviour with lots of other things breaking). I've tried jquery.cycle.lite - same behaviour.

```
css:
root { 
    display: block;
}

.pics {
    height:  432px;
    width:   432px;
    padding: 0;
    margin:  0;
}

.pics img {
    padding: 15px;
    border:  1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #eee;
    width:  400px;
    height: 400px;
    top:  0;
    left: 0
}
div.pics {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

snippet:
<script type="text/javascript" src="caro/assets/jquery.cycle.all.2.72.js"></script>
<!--
  orenCaro core stylesheet
-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="caro/assets/caro.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.pics').cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
        pause: 100,
 cleartype: 1
    });
});

</script>


<div class="pics" id="pics">
img source
img source
img source
img source
</div>
<div> <br></br></div>

<!-- /MODULE caro -->
<!-- Module Editorial -->
<div id="editorial_block_center" class="editorial_block">
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all,  It appeared that IE7 doesn't like the way jquery.cycle renders \<\img src />.  So don't add any parameters to the \<\img src>.

Thanks
all.